# Saving current frame of video-Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, render, image-capture

I have a scenario where pick video from library and save frame as image on clicking a button. like we can capture current frame of video playing in wpf.

I had done this in Windows Phone 8-

```
        WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)media.ActualWidth, (int)media.ActualHeight);
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(media, new MatrixTransform());
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmpCurrentScreenImage.SaveJpeg(stream, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelWidth, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(stream);
                img.Source = bi;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        { }
```

but in Windows store app WritableBitmap class has no such function like SaveJpeg() so i used WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions from toolkit- `WriteableBitmap w = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(myMedia);
            w.Invalidate();
            thumb.Source = w;`
but it is not working for media element only.

On goggling I found post most similar to mine [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711054/how-do-i-grab-frames-from-a-video-stream-on-windows-8-modern-apps) but can't understand how can i use it since it is in C++ and I am creating my app with c#.

Comment: Have you managed to do this?

Comment: Saving current frame of media was not worked that time, giving black image when video was playing. I needed this to create thumbnail for video to save on server later I had to use default created thumbnail for video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emgu CV frame work for live capturing and also for working on video file.Here is the [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files) to the official page of Emgu community explaining this example.